# How do I make a drop-down inside a responsive table in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having a drop-down menu inside of a responsive table cuts off the dropdown links on mobiles, making it hard to use and ugly.

[Here is my code](http://www.bootply.com/YPYWoYuwkn), i'd really appreciate it if someone who knows how to make the drop-down appear over the table could tell me how.

Thanks!

[Drop-down cut off by table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXzne.png)

Comment: I would use the [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) for that particularly issue, then the user would have the ability to scroll all the options and select one (radio box)... or use CSS Media styles and show/hide one and the other depending on the viewport resolution

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bootply.com/O5TQWH5hPB

The problem is the `<div class="table-responsive">` don't have enough height to display everything, you can patch it with a `min-height` even if it may not be the best choice...

---

As said by @balexandre the [Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) seem a better choice, the drop-down seem not designed to be used in table...